# Mongo $group with $project

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get keyword count along with `parentId`, `categioryId` and `llcId`.
My db is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5673f5b1e4b0822f6f0a5b89"),
    "keyword" : "electronic content management system",
    "llcId" : "CL1K9B",
    "categoryId" : "CL1K8V",
    "parentId" : "CL1K8V",

}
```

I tried `$project` with `$group`

```
db.keyword.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$llcId",
            total: {$sum: 1},
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            categoryId: 1, total: 1
        }
    }
])
```

And it gives me a result like

```
{ "_id" : "CL1KJQ", "total" : 17 }
{ "_id" : "CL1KKW", "total" : 30 }
```

But I need actual data in result also e.g. `llcId`, `categoryId`, `keyword`, `total`. I tried to display `cetgoryId` and keyword by using `$project` but it displays only `_id` and total. What I am missing?

Comment: can u write an sample output that you required

Comment: Your aggregation pipeline will return the number of documents for each value of `llcId`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To get the `keyword` count you'd need to group the documents by the `keyword` field, then use the accumulator operator **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** to get the documents count. As for the other field values, since you are grouping all the documents by the keyword value, the best you can do to get the other fields is use the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator which returns a value from the first document for each group. Otherwise you may have to use the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** operator to return an array of the field values for each group:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$keyword",
            "total": { "$sum": 1 },
            "llcId": { "$first": "$llcId"},
            "categoryId": { "$first": "$categoryId"},
            "parentId": { "$first": "$parentId"}
        }
    }
];

db.keyword.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: how can i display $push operator data using angularjs ng-repeat

Comment: OK, but what if it ISN'T the first? For instance when using $min instead of Sum, "$llcId" can be paired with an "categoryId" that does not represent the minimum value of that document.

Answer (score 13):

You are grouping by `llcId` so it will give more than one `categoryId` per `llcId`.
If you want `categoryId` as in your result, you have to write that in your group query. For example:

```
db.keyword.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$llcId",
        total: {$sum: 1},
        categoryId:{$max:"$categoryId"}
    }

},
{
    $project: {
        categoryId: 1, total: 1
    }
}])
```