# Counting documents by user

Tags: mongodb, go

I need to count the number of documents owned by each user as well as display fields from the user. I know how to do it in SQL with Group By and Count() but have been unable to get it to work in Go with Mongodb (6). I then need to pass it to a Go template for display.

I can get part way with the following. But I have been unable to combine that with fields from the user list. If I add a $project stage, I just get all the documents and lose the summary.

I want to display something like:

`{user.username}, {user.account}, {user.email}, {user.doccount}`

Collections are Users, Documents, etc.

```
pipeline := `[
        {
            "$group": { 
                "_id": "$Username", 
                "doccount": { "$sum": 1 } 
            }
        }]`

    cursor, err := DocCollection.Aggregate(context.Background(), MongoPipeline(pipeline))
    ...
```

What am I missing? Or... Am I approaching this wrong? Should I make two separate queries and combine the results in a Map?

Thanks

Comment: I think this may be the solution you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35177196/7426